# Problem while deploying Java AWS lambda from Intellij IDE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to deploy the java aws lambda function from Intellij, When deploying I'm getting an error **SAM did not complete successfully**

The build and package were successful, but Create Change Set is resulting in error. Attaching the screen shot

**Build**
[image]

**Package**
[image]

**Create Change Set**

While running create change set I'm getting the error

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: my guess would be, your aws-cli requires an update, can you check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aws-cli may be out dated. SAM might be passing arguments to the cli that are not supported by the version of your aws-cli. Try and update your aws-cli.

Comment: Yep after upgrading awscli and aws-sam-cli it worked

Comment: Glad to be of help